# What is the difference between an abstract class and a class that has all its methods abstract?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I wonder what is the difference in Java between an *abstract* class and a class that has all its methods *abstract*? I mean, is an *abstract* class just a class whose methods automatically get *abstract*?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Absolutely not. Indeed, a class can be abstract without *any* methods being abstract, although that's relatively rare (see Mark's comment below for an example). On the other hand, if a class has *any* abstract methods, then it *must* be declared abstract.

Generally speaking, the purpose of an abstract class is to provide a skeleton with *some* non-abstract behaviour, but other bits still to be filled in by subclasses. This can be used with the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), for example.

Comment: Do you mean if a class has any abstract methods (not if a method has any abstract methods)?  I'm not about to edit a response from you without being sure..

Comment: Some of the only valid uses of an abstract class with no abstract methods I've seen are the GUI adapter classes in Swing like MouseAdapter: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html.  The purpose of the class is to provide default no-op implementations (but still implemented!) of a bunch of methods to reduce boilerplate, yet it makes no sense to instantiate the class as-is.

Comment: It's probably important to point out that abstract classes cannot be instantiated, only subclassed. Also, if a subclass doesn't add bodies to **every** abstract method of its parent, it too must be declared abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Any class that contains one or more abstract methods must also be declared abstract. To declare a class abstract, you simply use the abstract keyword in front of the class keyword at the beginning of the class declaration. There can be no objects of an abstract class. That is, an abstract class cannot be directly instantiated with the new operator. Such objects would be useless, because an abstract class is not fully defined. Also, you cannot declare abstract constructors, or abstract static methods. Any subclass of an abstract class must either implement all of the abstract methods in the superclass, or be itself declared abstract.

Answer (score 1):

The Only difference between abstract class and interface is that abstract class can be inherited and whereas interfaces can't, thus interfaces don't have any  constructors conversely with an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a abstract  method in the class then you explicitly mention the abstract keyword before the class name, just like this

```
public abstract class Test {

abstract void show();
```

}

Here are the points related Abstract class in Java

-->Abstract class is the one of class that cannot be instantiated.

-->If you want to get implementation of any method from child class(other person) then abstract method can use in this sense.

-->Abstract class are incomplete ,subclass must declare missing piece to become concrete class(Class whose object can be instantiated ) , otherwise these subclass also become abstract class.

-->You can achieve abstraction that is main pillar of OOP through by "abstract classes".
Abstraction hide the irrelevant detail of an object.

-->Abstract use for IS A Relationship (Inheritance).

-->Abstraction use for to achieve Polymorphic behavior (Another main pillar of OOP)

-->abstract class should not be private and not contained private method.

-->You extends single abstract class not multiple because Java is Single supported Inheritance

--> Abstract class must contain  1 or more than 1 abstract method

-->If any class contain abstract method then it should explicitly declare abstract class even if it contain  concrete method.

--> Constructor and static method cannot be declared as abstract because constructor are not inherited.

--> If child class have not implement the abstract method of super class then it become also abstract class.

-->Attempting to instantiate the object of abstract class is an Compilation error.

-->Abstract super class variable can hold the reference of child concrete object.

Answer (score 0):

A class which contains the abstract keyword in its declaration is known as **abstract class**.

- Abstract classes may or may not contain **abstract methods ie., methods with out body ( public void get(); )**
- But, if a class have at least one abstract method, then the class must be declared abstract.
- If a class is declared abstract ,it cannot be instantiated.
- To use an abstract class you have to inherit it from another class, provide implementations to the abstract methods in it.
- If you inherit an abstract class you have to provide implementations to all the abstract methods in it.
- 

If you don't want to provide implementation for all abstract methods then there is a **concept** of **adapter class**:
Example:

```
abstract class A{
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
    public void m3();
    }

class B extends A{
    public void m1(){}
    public void m2(){}
    public void m3(){}
    }


class C extends B{
    public void m2(){
       System.out.println("Hello m2");
       }
    public static void main(String args){
     C obj=new C();
    C.m2();
    }
    }
```